# Git in Eclipse, Pull is greyed out

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I'm using git in Eclipse. Both the "merge" and "pull" options are greyed out for the module that I'm working on. What causes that to happen? "Fetch from Upstream" and everything else works as normal.

Comment: Are you sure you are working on a specific branch? (you might checked out to some arbitrary commit id)

Comment: Can you add more info? what does 'git status' show? how does your .git/config looks like?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse Neon?

Comment: @ItayB I think that might be it. Instead of showing the branch number next to the package name, it's just a weird string (which I guess is the commit ID). How do I get back to working on the branch?

Comment: I've added answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the command:
git checkout master

Or any other branch you are working on
Before doing it, backup your job! You might lost some changes if you didn't commit them!
If it doesn't let you checkout, do:
git reset --hard
(After backup)

Note that you can also do it from the GUI with checkout..